# QGIS Distance Matrix - with line geometry output?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line, distance-matrix

I have a series of Output Area centroids and I want to create a matrix of lines between each point (every point connected to every point), which is effectively what the distance matrix tool does (I think). But I also need the line geometry for visualisation purposes. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `Distance matrix` output, use its `InputID` and `TargetID` fields to build connecting lines.

[image]

Just open the `Layer properties | Symbology` and select `Geometry generator`.

[image]

If your original point layer name is `points` and it has `id` field (the one you used to create the Distance matrix), the expression would be:

```
make_line(geometry(get_feature('points', 'id', "InputID")), 
          geometry(get_feature('points', 'id', "TargetID")))
```

It will give you these connecting lines:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. In the end I used the 'Geometry by Expression' tool to generate a permanent output, using the code you provided.

Comment: It does not seem to work on my QGIS 3.12.2

Answer (score 0):

With polygons, you can use the plugin "conefor" (you can convert point to polygon with a buffer and dont activ the option "edge distance")

[image]

With points, may be you can use the plugin "MMQGIS".
You have here a tutorial that can help : [hub line](http://www.qgistutorials.com/fr/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html)